# how to print specific lines from an array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, string, polymorphism, singleton

So Im trying to print only the novels added to the array and I cant figure out how..
Also I need to return the number of books of a specific kind.
Im new to programming so please take me easy :)

Here is the app, I have to add all the books from console
Each word added from console triggers a specific action so to print the books I need to write print, to add i need to write add , type of book, title of book, author, and so on.

```
import java.util.*;
public class App{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Library bib = Library.getInstance();
        String line = "";
        line = s.nextLine();
        String[] v = line.split("\\s+");
        while(true){
        switch(v[0]){
            case "add": 
                String title = v[2];
                String autor = v[3];
                Book c = null;
                if("story".equals(v[1])){
                    c  = new Story(title, autor);
                } else if("novel".equals(v[1])){
                    int pages = Integer.parseInt(v[4]);
                    c = new Novel(title, autor, pages);
                } else if("poetry".equals(v[1])){
                    String publish = v[4];
                    c = new Poetry(title, autor, publish);
                }
                bib.adauga(c);
                break;
            case "print" : 
            case "return" : 
            case "exit" : System.exit(0); break;
            default : System.out.println("Command " + v[0] + " does not exist");
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Library{
    private static Library instance;
    List<Book> books;

    private Library(){
        books = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Library getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Library();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void adauga(Book c){
        books.add(c);

    }

    public void afisare(){
        for(Book c : books){
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }


}
```

---

```
public abstract class Book{
    String title;
    String autor;

    public Book(String title, String autor){
        this.title=title;
        this.autor=autor;
    }

     @Override
    public String toString(){
        return  title + " " + autor;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Novel extends Book {
    int pages;

    public Novel(String title, String autor, int pages){
        super(title, autor);
        this.pages=pages;
    }

     @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " " + pages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not JS, no need to put in snippet, not executable here

Comment: Sorry but if I put it normally the code was looking like I wrote it on a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a method that print all the `books` of the`Library`, you need to modify it to print the good type of book :

Use `print novel` for example :

```
// in App
case "print" : bib.afisare(v[1]);
               break;
```

---

```
// in Library
public void afisare(String type){
    for(Book c : books){
        if("novel".equals(type) && c instance of Novel)
            System.out.println(c);
        else if("story".equals(type) && c instance of Story)
            System.out.println(c);
        else if("poetry".equals(type) && c instance of Poetry)
            System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

---

Also, because of your `while(true)` you are going to run in infinite loop, you need to ask again after the switch *or* don't ask before and use `do{}while();`

```
do{
    line = s.nextLine();
    String[] v = line.split("\\s+");
    switch(v[0]){ 
        ... 
    }
}while(true);
```

Comment: I dont need to print all the books I need to print only specific ones, I have more books in code but I didnt post them, I have poetry and story too. I mean I need to print only novel books. or only poetry books from array

Comment: @AlexCristea what command will you type to print all novels ? `print novel` ?

Comment: @AlexCristea i've edit, with the command, just add the type after print

Comment: Forgot to mention, Im getting a heap space outofmemoryerror after trying to add a book . Have any idea why , and thank you for your help

Comment: @AlexCristea because of `while(true)` the book is added infinite time, until no memory, fix it with my edit of 5min ago ;) at the end of the post

Comment: @AlexCristea sure ? and when do you type it ? with you code the exit command will work only of you write it first, but of not you never ask again the user, think about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use instanceof to check what the type of an object is.

```
//Go through every book
for(Book book : bib.books){
    if(book instanceof Novel){
         System.out.println(book);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables from other objects by using '.' as long the variable is in visibility (e.g. public or in same package) or you use getter methods.

So in your case you can do something like this.

```
final List<Book> books = Library.getInstance().getBooks();
for(Book book : books) {
    if(book instanceof Novel) {
        System.out.println(((Novel)book).toString());
    }
}
```

## need to add to Library

```
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return this.books;
}
```

This is just a simple example how you can use your books and pages with your example, feel free to edit and use it as you need to.

Comment: No need to cast in the print, cause of polymorphism